# Typescript & inheritance - calling a static method from non-static method

Tags: typescript, methods, static

Example code (simplified):

```
class Base {
   public static x: number;

   private static f() {
       console.log("static function's x is " + this.x);
       return this.x;
   }

   public g() {
      return Base.f();
   }

}

class Child extends Base {
    x = 5;
}

class OtherChild extends Base {
    x = 10;
}

const obj = new Child();
console.log("object's x is " + obj.x);
obj.g();
```

Another class creates a Child object.
Looking at the child object I see x is set to 5.
Then I call g(), and inside it x is still defined as 5, and the type of "this" is Child.
Now g() calls f(), and inside it x is undefined, and the type of "this" is now Base.

I assume this is because I use Base.f(), but I can't use "this".
How can I call the static method of the base class from the non-static method without losing my object?

To clarify, I have static property that every child should have, so I want to define once it in the base class.
Every child has a different value for it, and the common functions in the base use this property (and obviously its value should depend on the subclass it was called from)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/W48VOW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: edited with working code example

Comment: Why do you want an instance of `Child` to modify a static property of `Base`? Not sure what the use case is.  But you can do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0ovxN); does that work for your needs?  If so, I can write up an answer; if not, could you describe your use case more clearly and what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Well it's a static property that every child should have, so I want to define once it in the base class. 
Every child has a different value for it, and the common functions in the base use this property (and obviously its value should depend on the subclass it was called from).
Your solution sets the Base's property's value, so there's actually only one.
Multiple subclasses can't have different values like this

Comment: So you don’t want *instances* of subclasses to set the static property.  Have you considered just making the property `static` in the child class?  Oh maybe I see, you want to use `this.constructor` in the base class's method (but [TS doesn't strongly type that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) so you need an assertion) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9yV7N) perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the moment I call Base.f() I am in the context of the base class, and the property is undefined.  
I tried defining x in the subclass and using a getter defined in the base class but it has the same issue.  
I'm rewriting the code to separate the statics to separate singleton classes, and then I won't have to use static methods/properties. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I feel like [this code here](https://tsplay.dev/N9yV7N) does what you want, but if not, can you explain why not?  You shouldn't call `Base.f()`, you should call `this.constructor.f()`.  It's `this.constructor` that gives you access to the static side of a class from the "non-static" (usually called "instance") side of the class.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for.  
I already separated the classes and I feel like it's cleaner, but I learned something new.. 
 
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `this` from a `static` method it returns the class because you called the function from the class (`Base.f()`) and it's what `static` methods are meant for.

That being said, your code works as expected, but `x` is not being overridden by the subclass as you expect, because it's `static` (attached to the class) in the `Base` class and it's a class field (attached to the instance) in the `Child` class so they're two different things.

Comment: So how do I set the value of Base's x from the child class?

Comment: Yes or even without a setter: `Base.x = 2;`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't compile

Comment: Well it should do, this is probably due to some TS config option. What's the error message?

Comment: Unexpected keyword or identifier. same for both my IDE and TS Playground

Comment: Well where are you writing the code? In the class body? You should do it in a function or method